# d3 using a different X scale and Y scale domain for each selection

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, d3.js

Here is the project on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLnB3/

I have data that is in this format:

```
var data = [
{
    "category": "Category1",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "subcategory": "Subcategory1A",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comment" : "1Acomment1",
                    "count": 8,
                },
                {
                    "comment": "1Acomment2",
                    "count": 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "subcategory": "Subcategory1B",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comment": "1Bcomment1",
                    "count": 11,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "subcategory": "Subcategory1C",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comment": "1Ccomment1",
                    "count": 2,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "category": "Category2",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "subcategory": "Subcategory2A",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comment": "2Acomment1",
                    "count": 6,
                },
                {
                    "comment": "2Acomment2",
                    "count": 9,
                },
                {
                    "comment": "2Acomment3",
                    "count": 9,
                },
                {
                    "comment": "2Acomment4",
                    "count": 9,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "subcategory": "Subcategory2B",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "comment": "2Bcomment1",
                    "count": 14
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

];

I want to create a bar chart for each category. So Category 1 will be a bar chart, Category 2 will be a bar chart, and so on (there are many more categories). Each category has a different number of subcategories and each subcategory has a different number of comments (ranging from 1 - 30). In each bar chart, the comments will be populating the X axis. So for each chart I need to produce something like this:

```
<svg id="Category1">
  <g>
    <g class="xAxis">...</g>
    <g class="yAxis">...</g>  
    <g class="subcategory" id="Subcategory1A">
      <g class="comment" id="1Acomment1">
        <rect height="8"></rect>
        <text>8</text>
      </g>
      <g class="comment" id="1Acomment2">
        <rect height="7"></rect>
        <text>7</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="subcategory" id="Subcategory1B">
      <g class="comment" id="1Bcomment1">
        <rect height="11"></rect>
        <text>11</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="subcategory" id="Subcategory1C">
      <g class="comment" id="1Ccomment1">
        <rect height="2"></rect>
        <text>2</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g> 
</svg>
<svg id="Category2">
...
</svg>
```

I'm using d3.select("body").selectAll("svg").data(data).enter().append("svg").... to create them all.

My problem is that since each different chart will have a different number of xAxis ticks I have no idea how to set the domain for the ordinal scale for each chart's xAxis. Same problem with the linear scale for the yAxis because I normally do [0, d3.max(...)] for that one, but that will be different for each bar chart as well.

This is what I have so far:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    //.domain(???help???)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .3);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    //.domain(???help???)
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.category})
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")  
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(-25)" 
        });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var subcategory = svg.selectAll(".subcategory")
    .data(function(d){ return d3.values(d.subcategories);})
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "subcategory")
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.subcategory;});

var comment = subcategory.selectAll(".comment")
    .data(function(d){return d3.values(d.comments);})
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "comment")
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.comment;});

comment.append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d){
      return height - yScale(d.count);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
    .attr("y", function(d){
      return yScale(d.count);
    });

comment.append("text")
    .text(function(d){ 
        return d.count; 
    })
    .attr("x", xScale.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d){ 
        return yScale(d.count) - 5;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "#353535")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

This, of course, makes the axes and the width, height, x, and y attributes on the rectangle and text elements go all crazy. This is following a basic bar chart template that I've used several times and always works fine when I only have 1 xscale domain and 1 yscale domain.

So how do I set the xScale domain? And yScale domain? How do I grab each comment out of a Category and say "these will be the xScale for this chart"? Remember, some of the charts will have 30 comments, some will have 7 comments, some will have a max comment count of 200 some will have a max comment count of 2. They are variable for each chart. So if I'm using d3 to create an SVG element for each category in the data array, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The xScale and yScale is going to vary for each category chart, because they have different domains (max value in the case of the y scale). Therefore I'd recommend you create separate ones within an each call as in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T69xt/)

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.category})
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .each(function(d, i){
        var svg = d3.select(this); 
        var allComments = d.subcategories.reduce(function(prev, curr, i, array){
             return prev.concat(curr.comments);
        }, []);
        var xDomain = allComments.reduce(function(prev, curr, i, array){
            prev.push(curr.comment);
            return prev;
        }, []);
        var yMax = d3.max(allComments, function(comment) {
          return comment.count;  
        })

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(xDomain)
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .3);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, yMax + 2]) // giving ticks specific padding
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5);   


        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")  
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "rotate(-25)" 
                });
....
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to find the range-of-values within your dataset.  To accomplish that you can do something like:

```
// find data range

var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d){ return Math.min(d.comments); });
var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d.comments); });

// or use d3.extent like so
var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function (d, i){ return d.category; });

// scale and add range
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(xDomain)
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([yMin, yMax])
    .range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom]);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback but that made all charts have the same xAxis ticks, and the values of the ticks were from the category level (they need to be from the comment level).

Comment: You can create a unique domain for each chart by repeating that pattern with the selected data.  just create new var for xDomain2, xDomain3, etc and plug in d.yourDataPoint in the Min/Max or extent.

Comment: @DeBraid how you can do this? I'm struggling to figure it out.