# d3 nested data - individual graphs - setting y.domain?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to turn some nested data into 8 individual line charts (one chart for each key). So far I am creating one graph per svg, however I am having issues with the `y-domain` - specifically setting the `y-domain` for each graph.

currently:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.app); })

x.domain(d3.extent([parseDate("2003.0"), parseDate("2014.0")]));
y.domain(d3.extent([0,20000]));

var data2 = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.race; })
  .entries(data);

var svgContainer = d3.selectAll("body")
    .data(data2)
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .append("path")
    .data(data2)
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.key ;})
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('opacity', .8)
    .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); });
```

I see parts of some lines in the svg's, but most are cut off. Any suggestions? I'm not sure if the paths are correct either.

Data:

```
    { key: "1", values: 0: ['app' : 50000, year: '2003'], 1: ['app': 20000, year: '2004'], 
      key: "2" values: 0: ['app' : 40000, year: '2003'], 1: ['app' 50000, year: '2004']
    etc...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified [d3 using a different X scale and Y scale domain for each selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712671/d3-using-a-different-x-scale-and-y-scale-domain-for-each-selection)

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").selectAll(".line")
    .data(data2)
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top+ ")")
    .append("g")
    .each(function(d, i){

        var eachRace = d.values;
        console.log(eachRace);
        var svg = d3.select(this);
        var yMax = d3.max(eachRace, function(d) { return d.app; });
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yMax]).range([height/8, 0]);
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.app); })

        svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key ;})
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('opacity', .8)
        .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); })

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
    })
```

Comment: how to get the current g inside each?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `extent` directly to your data like so:

```
 yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.app; }));
```

This will give you the extent of all the data. If you need to get the extent of portions of the data, such as in your case of one category vs. another, you need to get the extent of the result of some filtering function. You should look into either `d3.filter` or write your own within `extent()`. So you'd probably want to make the return value contingent on d.key matching your current key, however you are storing that.

Comment: I was  thinking of that but my data is formatted as the above edit... wouldn't I be a level up then?

Comment: I tried implementing this - but my paths are still outside of the svg (when i scroll over them in firefox and it shows where they are displayed). so perhaps it worked and I'm running into another issues?

Comment: Oh that did work actually - it seems to be other problems with the `range` that are affecting the paths

Comment: Ah sorry to go back and forth - it actually didn't work. It set the same domains for all of them, using the max of `d.app` for all the `keys`, not the specific `key` for that graph

Comment: @As3adTintin I have updated my answer above. I have not done this before, but that is my best guess.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'm currently working with `y.domain(yExtent = d3.extent(data.filter(function(d, i) { return +d.key - 1 == i }), function(d) { return d.app; });)` but still having trouble getting it to work